# Oracle - PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements

Tags: oracle

I am new to programming in ORACLE and I am trying to compare a table column value to a passed in array and I am having a rather frustrating time in doing so.

Here is the Type Declaration from the package head.

```
TYPE T_STRING_ARRAY IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(5);
```

and here is the the function that is using it.

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY TEST_PACK IS 

  FUNCTION TEST_LOG_FN 
  (
        PI_START_DATE IN VARCHAR2,
        PI_END_DATE IN VARCHAR2, 
        PI_LOG_TYPE IN T_STRING_ARRAY
  )
   RETURN T_REF_CURSOR
    AS  
    PO_RESULT T_REF_CURSOR;

  BEGIN   


  OPEN PO_RESULT FOR
  SELECT
        EL.ENTRY_BASE_LOG_ID,
          EL.APP_NAME,
          EL.APP_MODULE,
          EL.CREATION_DATE,
          EL.APP_STATUS,
          EL.LOG_TYPE
    FROM 
          LG_ENTRY_BASE_LOG EL
  WHERE     
          CREATION_DATE > PI_START_DATE AND
          CREATION_DATE  < PI_END_DATE AND              
         (EL.LOG_TYPE IN PI_LOG_TYPE OR PI_LOG_TYPE = NULL);

  RETURN 
      PO_RESULT;

EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
           RETURN NULL;
       END TEST_LOG_FN;
END;
```

The error I am getting is PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements. I have read online

"To avoid the PLS-00642, the collection will need to be defined at the schema level; therefore, you would need to define the varray table as a real table, using Oracle DDL with the CREATE TYPE syntax. "

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pls_00642_local_collection_types_not_allowed_in_sql_statement.htm

I am not sure how to do that nor have I found any references online that I could use. Can someone help me with that? If someone knows an easier way to see if a string exists in an array, that is a perfectly acceptable answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use types defined in the package spec in Oracle 12C or later.

This line:

```
(EL.LOG_TYPE IN PI_LOG_TYPE OR PI_LOG_TYPE = NULL)
```

Needs to be:

```
(EL.LOG_TYPE IN (select column_value from table(PI_LOG_TYPE))
OR (select count(*) from table(PI_LOG_TYPE)) = 0)
```

Prior to 12C you need to define the type in the database using CREATE TYPE.  The syntax for the select is the same either way.

Comment: THank you for the quick response. I am now getting  new error that says:

PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item. Starting at the word "table"

Comment: What Oracle version are you using?

Comment: OK, you can't write `PI_LOG_TYPE = NULL`.  It should have been `P1_LOG_TYPE IS NULL` anyway, but to test whether a collection is empty in SQL you need to `select count(*)` from it. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `IN` you can use the [`MEMBER OF`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjcol.htm) operator designed specifically for use with collections:

```
(PI_LOG_TYPE = NULL OR EL.LOG_TYPE MEMBER OF PI_LOG_TYPE);
```

As noted by @TonyAndrews If you are using Oracle 12c then you can use collections defined in a package in PL/SQL but in earlier versions you will need to define them in SQL using the `CREATE TYPE` statement.